# Is redirecting to null the proper way to discard a line in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement

I'm in the process of integrating two pieces of software that talk to each other via CSV files, but the output file from App A requires a bit of post-processing before App B can pick it up.

The code below appends data to lines beginning with "C," while discarding the other three possibilities for now, as those parts will be added at a later date.

$_ > null is something I came up with because I couldn't find a code snippet that would remove a line within a IF statement. It seems to work, but I want to be sure if it's correct.? TIA

```
$original = "input.txt"
$destination = "output.txt"
$tempfile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
get-content $original | foreach-object {
  if ($_ -match "^C,") {
    $_ + ",append this" >> $tempfile
  }
  elseif ($_ -match "^J,") {
    $_ > null
  }
  elseif ($_ -match "^B,") {
    $_ > null
  }
  elseif ($_ -match "^O,") {
    $_ > null
  }
  else {
    $_ >> $tempfile
  }
}
copy-item $tempfile $destination
remove-item $tempfile
```

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you don't actually need to put anything in those elseif blocks. There isn't anything wrong with redirecting to null either though.

Comment: Yep, that works! The result is in fact the same as redirect to null. So I can just leave the blocks empty until something else needs to happen with those lines. Thanks!

Comment: For thess things they have the keywords Continue, Break, Return and Exit. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-5.1 for the full documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't applicable for what you're doing, but it answers your initial question:

You have four options to suppress the `stdout` stream (also referred to as `&1`, `success`, or `output`).

1. `[Void]()` type-casting
2. `$Null = ()` assignment
3. `() > $Null` redirection
4. `() | Out-Null` cmdlet (note this is the slowest of the options by an order of magnitude)

---

This code block should address your problem:

```
$original = 'input.txt'
$destination = 'output.txt'
$tempfile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

Switch -Regex -File $original
{
    '^C,' { "$_,append this" | Out-File -FilePath $tempfile -Append }
    '^[JBO],' { }
    'Default' { $_ | Out-File -FilePath $tempfile -Append }
}
Copy-Item -Path $tempfile -Destination $destination
Remove-Item -Path $tempfile
```

---

Extra information on `Switch`:

> The `Default` keyword specifies a condition that is evaluated
>   only when no other conditions match the value.
>
> The action for each condition is independent of the actions in
>   other conditions. The closing brace ( `}` ) in the action is an
>   explicit `break`.

Comment: The perfect way to handle what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @David Glad to be of service. I noticed I forgot something in my regex and updated the answer: `'^[JBO],'` (added comma)